# How to tell if a control comes from MasterPage

Tags: c#, webforms

When iterating through a collection of all controls on a page (from `Page.Controls` and those control's children and their children's children etc), how can you tell if the control came from the Page's Master Page?

The following seems to work, but feels a bit dirty. Is there a better way to get this information?

Update: Sorry, missed some code out earlier.

```
List<Control> allControls = GetAllControls(this.Page)
foreach (Control c in allControls)
{
       bool isFromMaster = c.NamingContainer.TemplateControl.GetType().BaseType.BaseType == typeof(MasterPage);
}
```

Where `GetAllControls` recursively gets all controls on a page

Thanks

Comment: You don't get access to the Master pages controls in a child page, only access to the master page itself?

Comment: This is at runtime, so the Page.Controls collection contains controls from both the master page and the actual page. From MSDN: "At run time, the master page is merged with the content page, so the controls on the master page are accessible to content page code" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I don't think that will work for controls inside nested templated controls.  See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution turned out to be going through the controls from the master page, excluding the children of content place holders (as these give you the controls added from the page itself).

```
public static bool IsFromMasterPage(Control control)
{
    if (control.Page.Master != null)
    {
        // Get all controls on the master page, excluding those from ContentPlaceHolders
        List<Control> masterPageControls = FindControlsExcludingPlaceHolderChildren(control.Page.Master);
        bool match = masterPageControls.Contains(control);
        return match;
    }
    return false;
}    

public static List<Control> FindControlsExcludingPlaceHolderChildren(Control parent)
{
    List<Control> controls = new List<Control>();
    foreach (Control control in parent.Controls)
    {
        controls.Add(control);
        if (control.HasControls() && control.GetType() != typeof(ContentPlaceHolder))
        {
            controls.AddRange(FindControlsExcludingPlaceHolderChildren(control));
        }
    }
    return controls;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a reference to a `Control`, you could recursively look at the `Parent` property:

```
bool IsFromMasterPage(Control control)
{
    while(control.Parent != null)
    {
        if (control.Parent is MasterPage) return true;
        control = control.Parent;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, had a bit of a Friday afternoon moment when i checked this. The above code returns true for every control where the parent page uses a master page, as the parent of the page will always be a Mater page. So this doesn't actually tell you if the control itself came from the .master or the .aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

The `Page.Controls` **only contain controls from the current page**

If you want to check the MasterPage controls, use:

```
this.Master.Controls
```

On the other hand if you want to find the MasterPage controls on your page:

```
IEnumerable<MasterPage> masterPageControls = this.Page.Controls.OfType<MasterPage>();
```

Although you can have only one MasterPage associated to your page